# 7z is unable to archive files with umlaut

Tags: locale

I have a file named `foobarë`. When I try to 7zip it on Debian (stable) via Putty, I get the following:

```
server:/tmp#  7za a test.7zip foobarë

7-Zip (A) 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)
Scanning


foobarÃ«:  WARNING: No more files


Creating archive test.7zip



WARNINGS for files:

foobarÃ« : No more files
----------------
WARNING: Cannot find 1 file
```

Somewhere along the way the `foobarë` is converted to `foobarÃ«`. How can I fix this?

My locale on Debian (at least, the content of `/etc/locale.gen` and `locale -a`) is `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`.

Comment: This [forum post](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/forums/forum/45797/topic/3332513) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure PuTTY is in UTF-8 mode. Go to *Window → Translation*, under *Remote character set* choose *UTF-8*. Go back to *Session*, select *Default Settings* and click *Save*.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the version of 7-Zip you are using is an old version and if I remember correcly around the 9.04 area there were two versions of 7-zip, one which used the standard character set and another that was Unicode.

The current version of [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is 9.20, yours appears to be 9.04.  Can you update and try again?

There is also a bug report from the p7zip (Unix port of 7-zip) Sourceforge page that claims this was fixed since 9.13, so again I would recommend updating to 9.20 if possible: [Sourceforge Bugtracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2976169&group_id=111810&atid=660495)

Answer (score 0):

The answer might also be in Putty... Putty itself (Window->Translation) wasn't set to UTF-8. I've switchted to UTF-8 now, my `foobarë` file now has a weird name, when I make it again it 7zips correctly.